# How to shorten the height of an element in a column?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

I've made a row with for columns where each of them has a social media icon. For every row there is an anchor tag inside of a div element. Since this row is a column of another row, the height of the first one change automaticaly. The problem is whenever I hover the cursor below of a button [(shown with the white border)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJs0T.jpg), the pointer is showing up like I'm hovering it on the button.

[Also when I inspect the button itself it shows only button with its original height and the code shows the ::before attribute.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKFVs.jpg)

I'm using bootstrap as you could notice and tried to solve the problem by changing the padding or height but nothing works acutally.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row col-12 justify-content-between mx-0">
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"  style="border: 1px solid white;"></a></div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x" style="height:"></a></div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x" style="height:"></a></div>
    <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center"><a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" style="height:"></a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: mb-auto ? to the row

Comment: Thank you. Also I solved it by using (align-self: flex-start;). Is this way safe too?

Comment: yes but consider using the bootstrap classes, you can find one for align-self:flex-start